# Pi 1 B, Jessie Lite, SPI doesn`t work

Tags: jessie-lite, pi-b

Cannot get working SPI. Have checked on wheezy and it works perfectly.
On jessie /dev see only spi0.1, have tried both pins, but no result. Where is the problem?

`grep spi /boot/config.txt`:

```
#dtparam=spi=on
#dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod|grep spi  
    spi_bcm2835             7868  0 


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/spi*  
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Mar  5 20:32 /dev/spidev0.1


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a  
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.18+ #848 Mon Feb 29 13:55:31 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please edit your question and give the output of "grep spi /boot/config.txt", "lsmod|grep spi", "ls -l /dev/spi/*", and "uname -a".

Comment: Have you got any other overlays set up in /boot/config.txt?  Any which use SPI to communicate like a screen?

Comment: No, it`s only one. When I`m trying to turn on spi through raspi-config I get error **modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'spi_bcm2708': No such device**

Comment: spi_bcm2708 is the old SPI driver, spi_bcm2853 is new.  I'd be tempted to remove the spi dtoverlay line.  It shouldn't be needed.

Comment: dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0-overlay,oscillator=8000000,interrupt=25, not familiar with dtoverlay funcion, but I need to get working my spi can controller which has dtoverlay in boot config, but I have tried anyway to remove dtoverlay, no success.

Comment: The canbus overlay will be claiming a SPI interface.  That's probably what is screwing up your system.  Have you just tried using the canbus software?

Comment: Until system cannot recognize canbus controller, I can`t determine  bitrate and canbus network in network interfaces. When it works have to be something like this `pi@raspberrypi:~$  sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ifconfig can0
can0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)`

Answer (score 1):

check your config.txt, you also need to disable Device-Tree if you run a recent kernel, adding this line:

```
device_tree=
```

(yes, empty parameter) or use raspi-config to do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find the answer to your problem?
I recently switched an old project on Wheezy to Jessie Lite.  When I tried to run the python script, it gave me "ImportError: No module named 'spidev'"

After I spent most of a day trying to figure this out, I ran across an old blog with a list of python libraries.  Unfortunately, the blog was written in Japanese and I don't read Japanese but lo and behold, the list contained an entry "python-spidev"

So just for grins, I tried "sudo apt-get install python3-spidev" AND IT WORKED!

Just to see what is actually needed, I back-tracked to a much earlier (pre- SPI) version of my SD card that I was working on and simply enabled SPI via raspi-config and then installed python3-spidev.  That's all it took!